# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id    userid    int1    int2    string    string2   string3
 1     90       5067    1000     aaa        100       qqq

 1     90       6945    1000     bbb        101       qqq

 1     90       9596    1010     ccc        102       qqq
```

The desired output:

```
id    userid    int1                int2               string        string2        string3

1      90      [5067,6945,9596]    [1000,1000,1010]   [aaa,bbb,ccc]  [100,101,102]   qqq
```

I have tried to create a new dataframe for int1,int2,string,string2 and then merge them but this solution was very slow as I have a big dataset. A different solution is to use 'groupby':

```
df = df.groupby(['id','userid','string3']).[['int1'],['int2'],['string'],['string2']].apply(list).reset_index()
```

but this gives me  this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it necessary to return a single row with _int_ and _string_ columns containing lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `as_index=False` + [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) 
to return the columns in the initial order:

```
new_df=( df.groupby(['id','userid','string3'],as_index=False)
           .agg(list)
           .reindex(columns=df.columns) )
print(new_df)
```

---

If you want you could select the columns:

```
cols=['int1','int2','string','string2']
new_df=( df.groupby(['id','userid','string3'],as_index=False)[cols]
           .agg(list)
           .reindex(columns=df.columns) )
```

---

**Output**

```
   id  userid                int1                int2           string  \
0   1      90  [5067, 6945, 9596]  [1000, 1000, 1010]  [aaa, bbb, ccc]   

           string2 string3  
0  [100, 101, 102]     qqq
```

Comment: similarly `pivot_table` : `df.pivot_table(index=['id','userid','string3'],values=['int1','int2','string','string2']
               ,aggfunc=list).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing individual values (lists) within a list. You don't need to use doble brackets like you do when filtering a dataframe and expect a dataframe output. Hopefully this will work better for you:

```
df = df.groupby(['id','userid','string3'])['int1','int2','string','string2'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Comment: I missed the .dot